# Schengen visa application for non-consecutive trips

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, europe, tourist-visas

I'm planning to make 2 trips (for tourism) to the Schengen area. Trips are not consecutive. For example, I want to go to country 'A' in March for a week then leave the Schengen area.

In June, I want to go to country 'A' again and stay there for a week again then move to country 'B', which is also in Schengen, stay there less than a week then leave the Schengen area.

Is it possible/correct to state this in 'one' Schengen visa application? Or should there be separate applications for each trip in March and June? This will be my first Schengen application.

Answer (score 3):

It’s certainly possible, but whether it’s a good idea will depend a lot on your circumstances.

If your two trips were a lot closer, or they were for business, or if you already had received and used without issue multiple Schengen visas, then asking directly for a relatively long visa with multiple entries would probably be the most logical option.

But as this is not the case, it will depend a lot on the strength of your application: if have a very good, stable, and very-well paid job (by European standards, not local standards, if they are lower) or are just wealthy, then it shouldn’t be a problem.

If you are a lot more on the edge and/or come from a country with a bad economic situation or a bad reputation, then it’s probably best if you have a very simple, straightforward and strong application. Remember that you will have to provide evidence for both trips of your plans/itinerary, where you will be staying, how much it all costs, show that you can easily afford that, and that you still have every reason to go back home as planned, and most definitely before your visa expires. The simpler the better.

Answer (score 1):

To cut short ask for multiple entry visa.

Technically you should apply where you stay the most country A you can mention second country B also but there’s no need.

Think it’s always a good idea to provide plan based itinerary where you must ask clearly and outline without leaving guess work so in my opinion ask for multiple entry and iterate your plans on each entry.

Show them and justify that you need like 6 month  valid visa with multiple entry since you plan to travel on those planned date and the embassy will take note of that.

It’s important that you provide these travel plans as clear as possible but remember perhaps it’s a good idea to demonstrate these plans in the same country like say show Travel A country location A , then three month later show Travel A country location B . Once you are inside Schengen state it’s of irrelevance if you do stay 1 week or 2 week

If you do show sporadic plan here and there it might confuse the embassy who is reviewing your application so it’s a good idea to prove that you would be willing to go back and respect law of the land at the same time demonstrating the need for multiple entry visa with a need showing you cannot complete your trip in one go so you need more time